# Creating JSObject with JsArray from List[Long]

Tags: scala

I need to create a JsObject with JsArray from List[Long]. I though there is something called `JsLong`

```
def someWork(someList: List[Long]): JsObject = {
  JsObject(("someField", JsArray(someList.map(JsLong))) :: Nil)
}
```

apprently there is not. Any suggestion how I can create it?

Comment: JSON has no integer type, that's why you typically won't find it in JSON frameworks either.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one numeric type in JavaScript/JSON, and that's `Number`. It looks like you're using Play-JSON, which has `JsNumber`, which can be constructed with a `BigDecimal`. (Just convert the `Long` to a `BigDecimal`).

```
import play.api.libs.json._

def someWork(someList: List[Long]): JsObject = {
  Json.obj(
    "someField" -> JsArray(someList.map(a => JsNumber.apply(BigDecimal(a))))
  )
}

scala> someWork(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"someField":[1,2,3,4]}
```